# unable to create swagger definition of generic API response

Tags: swagger-3.0

My server application sends `json` response in the following format

```
{
result: ... //this could be success or error
additional-info: ... //this is a wrapper and could contains information depending the the operation
}
```

`additional-info` could be a success message (eg "operation successful"), error message (eg "operation failed") or say an object in string format (eg `{user-name: manu}`.

I have created `swagger` definition of the above object as follows:

```
ServerSuccessResponse:
      type: object
      properties:
        result:
          type: string
          enum:
            - success
        additional-info:
          type: string
          enum:
            - SuccessMessages
            - UserResponse
      required:
        - result
        - additional-info

    ServerFailureResponse:
      type: object
      properties:
        result:
          type: string
          enum:
            - error
        additional-info:
          type: string
          enum:
            - FailureMessages
```

Then I am trying to use the above definition in APIs as follows

```
  /user/username:
    post:
      tags:
        - new user
      summary: Add a new user to the database
      description: Use this path to add a new user
      requestBody:
        required: true
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/NewUser'
      responses:
        '200':
          description: means the user was added successfully
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/ServerSuccessResponse'#BUT ITS NOT CLEAR WHAT ADDITIONAL-INFO CONTAINS
        '404':
          description: >-
            Only a signed in user can add a question. This response means that
            the user isn't signed in.
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/ServerFailureResponse' #BUT ITS NOT CLEAR WHAT ADDITIONAL-INFO CONTAINS
        '500':
          description: >-
            means some internal error occur on the server while doing the
            operation. The state of the operation if un-determined and the
            operation could be successful, failed or partially successful
            (because some database operations are not rolled back if error
            occurs!
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/ServerFailureResponse'#BUT ITS NOT CLEAR WHAT ADDITIONAL-INFO CONTAINS
```

My issue is that at the moment, `ServerFailureResponse` or `ServerSuccessResponse` doesn't tell what `additional-info` would contain. I would like to redesign the API definition such that what is contained in the `additional-info` also gets clear. Is there a way I could do it? In code, I still want to use `additional-info` as wrapper. I only want that in `Swagger`, the content of `additional-info` is clear for each response.

Comment: Can you add some examples of real responses with various `additional-info` values, including the one with "an object in string format (eg `{user-name: manu}`"?

Comment: eg for 200 response - `{result:"success", additional-info:"{username:manu}"`, for 500 response  `{result:error, additional-info:"Operation unsuccessful"}` or 404 response `{result:"success", additional-info:"Not found"}`